Creating a ADLS Linked Service with Bicep for a Blob Container?
I can't get this ADLS Linked Service(LS) to work.
I tried publicAccess blob, container, and private for the container. I have allowBlobPublicAccess:true for the storage account. I was able to create functional LS for Kaggle with bicep. I'm running this on VS code. I've tried creating a ManagedID and assigning it roles for the storage and container in CLI.
The LS shows up in the data factory, but it fails when I test the connection.
Currently trying this:
resource adlsLinkedService 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices@2018-06-01' = {
  parent: dataFactory
  name: 'AdlsLinkedService'
  properties: {
    type: 'AzureBlobStorage'
    typeProperties: {
      servicePrincipalId: servicePrincipalId
      servicePrincipalKey: {
        type: 'SecureString'
        value: servicePrincipalKey
      }
      tenant: tenantId
      serviceEndpoint: 'https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net'
      }
  }
}

**This is the deployment of the relevent resources **
// Deploy the storage account (ADLS Gen2) for storing data
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2' 
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot' 
    isHnsEnabled: true 
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true 
  }
}

resource blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

// Create a container inside the ADLS Gen2 account for storing binary files
resource binaryContainer 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: blobService
  name: containerName // Name of the container
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'Container' // Public read access for the container
  }
}

resource dataFactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: dataFactoryName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned' // **Is this the problem?**
  }
}


Using the managed identity, you would need to grant it permission to access the storage:
// storage-account-role-assignment.bicep

param storageAccountName string
param roleId string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'

// reference to storage account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, storageAccountName, roleId, principalId)
  scope: storageAccount
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}

Then your main deployment could look like that:
// main.bicep
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param dataFactoryName string = 'df-thomastest-001'
param storageAccountName string = 'stthomastest001'
param containerName string = 'binary'

// Create data factory
resource dataFactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
  name: dataFactoryName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}

// Create a storage account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    isHnsEnabled: true
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
  }
}

// Associated blob service
resource blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
  properties: {}
}

// Create a container inside the ADLS Gen2 account for storing binary files
resource binaryContainer 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: blobService
  name: containerName // Name of the container
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
}

// Grant permission to storage
module dataFactoryStorageRbac 'storage-account-role-assignment.bicep' = {
  name: '${dataFactoryName}-${storageAccountName}-rbac'
  params: {
    storageAccountName: storageAccount.name
    principalId: dataFactory.identity.principalId
    roleId: 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe' // Storage Blob Data Contributor
  }
}

// Create link servie to blob
resource adlsLinkedService 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices@2018-06-01' = {
  parent: dataFactory
  name: 'AdlsLinkedService'
  properties: {
    type: 'AzureBlobStorage'
    typeProperties: {
      accountKind: 'StorageV2'
      serviceEndpoint: storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob
    }
  }
}

Here we created a Blob Storage linked service, if you want to create an Data lake storage linked service, you can use this:
// Create link servie to data lake storage
resource adlsLinkedService 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices@2018-06-01' = {
  parent: dataFactory
  name: 'AdlsLinkedService'
  properties: {
    type: 'AzureBlobFS'
    typeProperties: {
      url: storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints.dfs
    }
  }
}

Also you can create the linked service from data factory studio:

Publish then export the ARM template to see what has been generated and required:


Thank you. I got it to work shortly after posting the question. I ended up adding a Blob Data Contributor role to the data factory, which is basically what you suggested, right?

Yep that was the main point. you need to assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the data factory managed identity.
